# How to store a name and score into a list?

Tags: python-3.4

I have made a quiz but I want to store the name and score in the format **NAME:SCORE** into a list but I don't know how.
I have simplified the code down so it is easier to work with.

```
scores = ['Sam:10']
name = input("What is you name? ")
score = input("What score did you get? ")
```

How would I store the name and score into the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will add them to the list:

```
scores.append({'name': name, 'score': score})
```

But I would change your first line as well to:

```
scores = [{'Name':'Sam': 'Score':10}]
```

Alternatively, if you want to keep them as a string, just do this:

```
scores.append("%s:%s" % (name, score))
```

Comment: Thanks, it doesn't Seem to crash but it doesn't seem to appear in the list when the code has finished running. That's the part I'm struggling on.

Comment: Check to make sure the expected values are getting stored in name and score and try printing the value of scores are various times in the program to see what is happening. It's hard to debug it further without seeing more of the code.

Comment: I meant to say it doesn't store it in the list, when I go to the programming window, This is the part of the code that I use to store it:                                                      if name not in class1:                                                                 class1.append("%s:%s" % (name, score))

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean by "programming window"? You will likely need to print something in order to see the result of the program.

Comment: The progamming window, as in not the shell but the window where you write all the code and save it.